# Trouble finding duplicates using LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list of `ForecastData` and it looks like this:

```
public class ForecastData
{
    public string SalesID {get;set;}
    public string Customer {get;set;}
    public string Vendor {get;set;}
    public string Division {get;set;}
    public int Year {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}
```

I need to display a list of every distinct "SalesID" for each "Customer" that has an Amount > 0 where the year is THIS YEAR.

Currently, I'm grouping by Customer, but because I can have multiple "Amounts" for the same Customer and SalesID in my dataset, I'm not getting the results I expect. My results show:

1. Customer1 User1 $100
2. Customer1 User1 $200
3. Customer1 User1 $300
4. Customer1 User2 $100
5. Customer1 User2 $200

But what I want is

1. Customer1 User1 $600
2. Customer1 User2 $300

Here's my expression:

```
var forecasts = (List<ForecastData>)cache.Get(_RAW_FORECAST_DATA_KEY, null);

foreach(var custGroup in forecasts.Where(f => f.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).GroupBy(f => f.Customer))
{
    if(custGroup.Count() > 1) // There's more than one forecast for this customer
    {
        foreach(var instance in custGroup)
        {
            toReturn.Add(new MultipleCustomer(custGroup.Key)
            {
                Salesperson = instance.SalesPersonId,
                Forecast = instance.Amount
            });
        }
    }
}

return toReturn;
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/491832/1466627).

Comment: You will definitely need to do a Sum on your instance.Amount. You're group by will only do a sort on the customer objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you change your query so that you have an "outer" `GroupBy` and an "inner" `GroupBy`, it will solve your problem:

```
var forecasts = (List<ForecastData>)cache.Get(_RAW_FORECAST_DATA_KEY, null);

var forecastGroups = forcasts
    .Where(f => f.Year = DateTime.Now.Year)
    .GroupBy(f => f.Customer)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .Select(grp => new { Key = grp.Key, SalesGroups = grp.GroupBy(f => f.SalesId) });

foreach(var custGroup in forecastGroups)
{
    if(custGroup.SalesGroups.Count() > 1)
    {
        foreach(var salesGroup in custGroup.SalesGroups)
        {
            toReturn.Add(new MultipleCustomer(custGroup.Key)
            {
                Salesperson = salesGroup.Key,
                Forecast = salesGroup.Sum(f => f.Amount)
            });
        }
    }
}

return toReturn;
```

Comment: I did this, but I'm still not getting the results I need. I feel like I need to first group by Customer, and if there's a Count > 1, THEN group by DISTINCT Salesperson and if there's more than one, I want to display all salespeople's amount sum for that customer

Comment: I just updated my answer, but based on your comment, I think I need to revise it a bit more.

Comment: Nah, didn't work. I agree with you though that I need an "outer" and "inner" group by...or at least I think I do.

Comment: I don't think I have access to my "Customer" grouping anymore, the only Key I get is salesperson (from that last GroupBy). Because of this, I couldn't create a `MultipleCustomer` object, which needs a Customer string, a Salesperson string, and a total forecast.

Comment: I just updated with the rest of the method. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, you have "custGroup.Key", but that doesn't work because custGroup is an IEnumable<IGrouping<string,ForecastData>>, so there is no key.

Comment: I see the problem...fixed. (I hope!) Note the change to the final `Select` in the query.

Comment: GOT IT! Awesome, thanks so much. I had to make 1 small change to make it return exactly what I need (added if(custGroup.SalesGroups.Count() > 1) around the inner "foreach". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
foreach(var custGroup in forecasts.Where(f => f.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).GroupBy(f => new { f.Customer, f.SalesPersonId }).Where(k => k.Count() > 1).Select(k => new { Customer = k.Key.Customer, SalesPersonId = k.Key.SalesPersonId, TotalAmount = k.Sum(x => x.Amount) } )
{
           toReturn.Add(new MultipleCustomer(custGroup.Customer)
           {
              Salesperson = custGroup.SalesPersonId,
              Forecast = custGroup.TotalAmount
           });
       }
   }
}
```

I have been writing it from my head. No C# compiler nearby, so there might be some errors.

The key to your problem here is that you need to aggregate your items summing their Amount's.

Comment: This just ends up giving me EVERY forecast, where the Amount is summed by a Customer/Salesperson grouping